# Php routing preg_match help needed

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a custom routing class, which allows me to do matches like this on requests:

```
'/[*:cat1]/[*:cat2]/?[*:cat3]/?[*:cat4]/?[p:page]/?'
```

Which will match the following links:

```
category-one/
category-one/cat-two/
category-one/cat-two/cat-three/
category-one/cat-two/cat-three/cat-four/
```

As you can see the ? after / means that parameter is optional.

My problem is with [p:page]/? which is also optional.

```
category-one/page-2/
category-one/cat-two/page-2/
category-one/cat-two/cat-three/page-2/
category-one/cat-two/cat-three/cat-four/page-2/
```

My problem is that when i try to match this link

```
/category-one/cat-two/page-2/
```

it will give me these params:

```
cat1 => category-one
cat2 => cat-two
cat3 => page-2
```

Instead of

```
cat1 => category-one
cat2 => cat-two
page => page-2
```

I am using this generated regexp:

```
`^(?:/(?P<cat1>[^/\.]+))(?:/(?P<cat2>[^/\.]+/)?)(?:(?P<cat3>[^/\.]+/)?)(?:(?P<cat4>[^/\.]+/)?)(?:(?P<page>(a^)|(?:pag-)(\d+)/)?)$`u
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!
Alex

Comment: Frustrates me ... lol  this approach is fundamentally flawed. `[^/\.]+` matches anything but `/` and `.` not sure why the dot is there or why it's escaped as `[^/.]+` is fine although I prefer `[^\/.]+` , Also of note is this `(?:pag-)` not `page-` but it doesn't really matter much.

Comment: What I mean by Fundamentally flawed, is it's to simplistic an approach for complex matching like this.  You would be better off with  `preg_match_all('/(?<cat>cat-)|(?<page>page-)/' .... )` and then loop over and process the results.  But it's non-trivial.  Personally I would make a token parser for it....

Comment: Sorry the pag vs page is a misspelling... What do you mean by token parser?

Comment: On my GitHub are several examples https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/tree/master/Lexers  You can do amazing things with them.  I can write on up quickly for you but I don't know the full schema of your url deal.

Comment: There I posted an answer that's the best I can do with the time and amount of information I have at the present moment. Hope it Helps!

Answer (score 2):

I would use a token lexer/parser approach.  I have a few examples on my git hub page at:

https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/tree/master/Lexers

These are others I have used to answer questions on SO, one is a JSON Object parser not a JSON string.  This would be malformed JSON without the `"` around the properties which `json_decode` can't handle.  The other is a HTML minifier (in an OOP style, same concept though) that you can exclude things like `<textarea>` tags from because white space matters there.  So you can do pretty much any kind of processing of text with this method.

I modified one, but I don't really know how you want the output or what you want to do with it, but it should get you started.  Probably you will have to integrate it into your URL routing class, which I have no idea what that looks like.  But this is a far better method to use then a simple `preg_match` because it gives you a place to preform complex logic on each segment of the match.

```
 //don't edit this part.
function parse($subject, $tokens)
{
    $types = array_keys($tokens);
    $patterns = [];
    $lexer_stream = [];
    $result = false;
    foreach ($tokens as $k=>$v){
        $patterns[] = "(?P<$k>$v)";
    }
    $pattern = "/".implode('|', $patterns)."/i";
    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
        //print_r($matches);
        foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $value) {
            $match = [];
            foreach ($types as $type) {
                $match = $matches[$type][$key];
                if (is_array($match) && $match[1] != -1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            $tok  = [
                'content' => $match[0],
                'type' => $type,
                'offset' => $match[1]
            ];
            $lexer_stream[] = $tok;
        }
        $result = parseTokens( $lexer_stream );
    }
    return $result;
}

//make changes here to how the tokens are dealt with
function parseTokens( array &$lexer_stream ){
    $result = [];

    while($current = current($lexer_stream)){
        $content = $current['content'];
        $type = $current['type'];
        switch($type){  
            case 'T_EOF': return;

            //custom code for you tokens.
            case 'T_DELIMTER': 
            case 'T_BASE': 
                //ignore these
                next($lexer_stream); //don't forget to call next
            break;
            case 'T_CAT':
                $cat = substr($content, 4);
                echo "This is Cat ".$cat."\n";
                next($lexer_stream);
            break;
            case 'T_PAGE':
                $page = substr($content, 5);
                echo "This is Page".$page;
                next($lexer_stream);
            break;

            //catch all token
            case 'T_UNKNOWN':
            default:
                print_r($current);
                trigger_error("Unknown token $type value $content", E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    if( !$current ) return;
    print_r($current);
    trigger_error("Unclosed item $mode for $type value $content", E_USER_ERROR);
}

/**
 * token should be "name" => "regx"
 * 
 * Order is important
 * 
 * @var array $tokens
 */
$tokens = [
    'T_EOF'             => '\Z',
    'T_DELIMTER'        => '\/',
    'T_BASE'            => 'category-one',
    'T_CAT'             => 'cat-(?:one|two|three|four)',
    'T_PAGE'            => 'page-\d+',
    'T_UNKNOWN'         => '.+?',
];

$subject = '/category-one/cat-two/page-2/';

parse($subject, $tokens);

echo "\n\n========================================\n\n";

$subject = '/category-one/cat-two/cat-three/cat-four/page-2/';

parse($subject, $tokens);
```

You can see it in action [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/97a0a5ec749526bb931bd281b60a2c25c4926b12)

Output of the above code:

```
//$subject = '/category-one/cat-two/page-2/';
This is Cat two
This is Page2

========================================

//$subject = '/category-one/cat-two/cat-three/cat-four/page-2/';
This is Cat two
This is Cat three
This is Cat four
This is Page2
```

How it works, this basically uses preg match all, but it is wrapped up in a convince type deal to make processing the output a bit easier and building the regular expression.  So instead of one monolithic Regx, you wind up with a smaller easier to deal with one.  It seems complicated at first but in reality once you understand what it does it makes it so so much easier.

You can even check the order if you want by adding some logic into the `parseTokens` function.  This should be the only place you have to edit stuff and mainly in the token switch statement.

The regx it creates is like this

```
/(?P<T_EOF>\Z)|(?P<T_DELIMTER>\/)|(?P<T_BASE>category-one)|(?P<T_CAT>cat-(?:one|two|three|four))|(?P<T_PAGE>page-\d+)|(?P<T_UNKNOWN>.+?)/i
```

So you can't add sub-capture groups note when I added the or in this one `cat-(?:one|two|three|four)` it's a non-capture group.  But you can just use `substr` to separate it later so it's no big deal.

The `\Z` is a bit obscure, but it just matches the end of the string without capturing anything.

Also the processing part is called like this (in `parse`):

```
$result = parseTokens( $lexer_stream );
...
return $result;
```

So you can return data that will get returned through the `parse` function to where you called it (if you wish)

```
  $something = parse($subject,$tokens);
```

I don't have the time right now to go into the full explanation of what a lexer is or how it all works.  So hopefully this is enough to get you started.

**UPDATE**

> It's a good start, but your code is very specific,

To counter this (don't get me wrong or take this the wrong way) I feal I need to explain it a bit further.

This is very generalized

```
$tokens = [
    'T_EOF'             => '\Z',
    'T_DELIMTER'        => '\/',
    'T_BASE'            => 'category-one',
    'T_CAT'             => 'cat-(?:one|two|three|four)',
    'T_PAGE'            => 'page-\d+',
    'T_UNKNOWN'         => '.+?',
];
```

This is very specific

```
`^(?:/(?P<cat1>[^/\.]+))(?:/(?P<cat2>[^/\.]+/)?)(?:(?P<cat3>[^/\.]+/)?)(?:(?P<cat4>[^/\.]+/)?)(?:(?P<page>(a^)|(?:pag-)(\d+)/)?)$`u
```

If you have to edit that it's going to be a huge problem, what if you want to route to books or something else.  How are you going to expand on that? I don't even know where to begin.

The array approach I have given you, you simple add it

```
$tokens = [
    'T_EOF'             => '\Z',
    'T_DELIMTER'        => '\/',
    'T_BASE'            => 'category-one',
    'T_CAT'             => 'cat-(?:one|two|three|four)',
    'T_PAGE'            => 'page-\d+',
    'T_BOOK'            => 'book-\w+',
    'T_UNKNOWN'         => '.+?',
];
```

Then you modify the switch statement:

```
  case 'T_BOOK':
       ///do something
  break;
```

And Bam you can do whatever you want in a clear and concise way. You can add whatever complex logic, what ever error checking etc... that you need to, very easily.

Comment: It's a good start, but your code is very specific, I don't know how to say this more properly. I have a routing class : https://pastebin.com/8YftMwNR - routes are like this: https://pastebin.com/x1Ui37bU and this is how I call the class : https://pastebin.com/DFPT1vrL - and I get the variables from the routes into $_params[]

Comment: it's not at all specific, in fact it's very general. What you need is specific which I cant do based on the fact I have no idea what your routing class looks like.  That is what you must change to use a method like this instead of trying to parse a complex string with a flat regex.

Comment: This method is 100% capable of `and I get the variables from the routes into $_params[]` producing an array of the parameters in a URL.  In fact I use a more complex system but very similar for my Event System in my framework I been working on ( although I don't have a working example of that, because I am re-writing some stuff) but it handles URLs in a similar fashion (something I've already tested).

Comment: I chose to re-write my Event Framework as separate Composer modules ( so I basically had to start over on it).  Sorry I don't have a working router that I can share with you but I designed something very similar using the same approach.  Using a simple regex is never going to be able to reliably handle the variations associated with this sort of thing.  It could handle a very well defined and simple sort of URL, but not something complex with variable parts to it.

Comment: There also seems to be a Bug with Stack Overflow with editing comments? :( that makes me sad.

Comment: Yes, it seems. Have a look at my comment after a refresh, i posted the routing class code entirely

Comment: I managed to solve it not via regexp :) i browse all params matched by preg_match and if the param matches '/page-([0-9]+)\/?/' i move it in the array to the 'page' key and remove it from the key where it was found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178221/discussion-between-alex-rosca-and-artisticphoenix).

Comment: yes but I see a lot of `preg_match_all` in there, just browsing over it your already half way to a lexer.  Eventually you will understand it as I do, it took me numerous attempts at the same thing before I realized what I was doing.  In case you missed it in my code `preg_match_all`

Comment: `i browse all params matched by preg_match` this is a work around (at best), if you are double processing the first set of matches.  In that case you could just as easily do `preg_match_all('/[^\/]+/` ....` and then reprocess what matches.  But again I don't know the full details on how you "fixed" it.  But hey it's your code, all I can do is offer some advice.

Comment: Yes, it's a workaround, the only problem is with the isolated 'page' param in the route, so it works just fine :) it's a workaround not a solution. The problem is that i can not rewrite the whole routing class... since the file is included in a lot o projects... And the only problem was with the 'page' params. thanks!

Comment: Sure, it almost motivates me to work on my Event Framwork, but alas I am to lazy/busy.