# Php preg_match optional slash not working properly

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex:

```
`^(?:/(?P<cat1>[^/\.]+/?)?)(?:(?P<cat2>[^/\.]+/?)?)(?:(?P<cat3>[^/\.]+/?)?)(?:(?P<cat4>[^/\.]+/?)?)(?:(?P<slug>[^/\.]+))-(?:(?P<id>[0-9]++))$`u
```

Which should work with

```
/cat-one/product-14
/cat-one/cat-two/product-14
/cat-one/cat-two/cat-three/product-14
/cat-one/cat-two/cat-three/cat-four/product-14
```

Problem is that only with the fourth one works good.

```
Array
(
    [cat1] => cat-one
    [cat2] => cat-two
    [cat3] => cat-three
    [cat4] => cat-four
    [slug] => product
    [id] => 14
)
```

The first three the 'slug' parameter has only one letter and the cat before gets the first letters:

```
Array
(
    [cat1] => cat-one
    [cat2] => cat-two
    [cat3] => produc
    [cat4] => 
    [slug] => t
    [id] => 14
)
```

I know the optional / is causing some problems, but i need it to match something else in the code and this regex is generated dinamically and I can not set a specific if for this case only.

```
(?P<cat1>[^/\.]+/?)?)
```

How can I make the / optional but still get the result I need?

Thanks!

LE: The problem here [preg match possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51900441/php-routing-preg-match-help-needed) was that i had different parameters optional and the preg_match was not matching them accordingly. The question above is different, since the problem is that because of a /? i get my slug broken in two.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php routing preg\_match help needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51900441/php-routing-preg-match-help-needed)

Comment: Just use [this way](https://regex101.com/r/PbzotJ/1) of building the optional parts.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's working, thanks! But, because I am creating this regexp dinamically and i use it in a routing class, i have a all other link no longer working... because in your example you removed the /? - can't i leave the /? there and still make it work in my example above?

Comment: Could you please precise what you may change?

Comment: This regex is generated by a function https://pastebin.com/d29nPaSu used to match other links like /cat-one/cat-two/cat-three/ or without the trailing slash /cat-one/cat-two/cat-three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make the `/` optional since the groups are optional.
This leaves the  *slug-id* intact each time.

`^/(?:(?<cat1>[^/.\r\n]+/)?)(?:(?<cat2>[^/.\r\n]+/)?)(?:(?<cat3>[^/.\r\n]+/)?)(?:(?<cat4>[^/.\r\n]+/)?)(?:(?<slug>[^/.\r\n]+))-(?:(?<id>[0-9]++))$`

https://regex101.com/r/Z64x8l/1

Readable regex

```
 ^ /
 (?:
      (?<cat1> [^/.\r\n]+ / )?      # (1)
 )
 (?:
      (?<cat2> [^/.\r\n]+ / )?      # (2)
 )
 (?:
      (?<cat3> [^/.\r\n]+ / )?      # (3)
 )
 (?:
      (?<cat4> [^/.\r\n]+ / )?      # (4)
 )
 (?:
      (?<slug> [^/.\r\n]+ )         # (5)
 )
 -
 (?:
      (?<id> [0-9]++ )              # (6)
 )
 $
```

Note, `\r\n` were added for multiline purposes. If you have a single line
string, just take that out.

Also, if you believe there may be more nesting before *slug-id* that you
don't account for, just add `(?:[^/.\r\r]+/)*` before the *slug* named group.

This will always keep the *slug-id* at the end.

Comment: As I wrote above in my reply to @Wiktor I use a function to generate this regex which after that is used in preg_match. The problem is that the same function is needed to generate a regex that will match other types of links like /cat-one/cat-two/cat-three/ or without the trailing slash /cat-one/cat-two/cat-three this is why i placed the /? at the end of each group.

Comment: So is there a way to make my regexp or yours have inside the regexp the / optional and work with my pattern?

Comment: @AlexRosca - You're missing something here bud.  You use the same regex `[^/.]` up to and including the _slug_. The slug is required, but since you've made `/?` optional, the first, second, third or fourth _cat_ term will consume all but the last character from the _slug_ term. There is only one way to do it. That was is as you see it in my answer. If you have any variation  source text, post it in your question and I'll take a look at it. Btw, I didn't read the comments, I just needed to look at your question to know what's wrong.